# How to use getattr to call a string as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, getattr

```
import pandas as pd

def test_run():
    for symbol in ['nugt', 'soxs']:
        for stat in ['max', 'min', 'mean']:
            print(f"{stat} Close")
            print(symbol, get_stat(symbol, stat))

def get_stat(symbol, stat):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{symbol}.csv")
    return getattr(df['close'], stat()) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    test_run()
```

I am trying to open up an 2 excel files (soxs.csv and nugt.csv) , look at the column "close" and find the max, min, mean in the "close" column for each file.

The result I am getting is `"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"`. But I am calling it with attributes that should run just trying to do it with less code by using a loop. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The`stat` is a string so you can call it, you can get the `attr` by like this:

```
return getattr(df['close'], stat)
```

It returns the method, for calling that you should use `()` and send the parameters if needed, like this:

```
return getattr(df['close'], stat)()
```

Comment: @EMZ if you think this was helpful please check the accept mark(the green one) beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `stat` which is a string at following line:

```
return getattr(df['close'], stat())
```

Change it to:

```
return getattr(df['close'], stat)()
```

Also, for accessing multiple attributes at once you can simple use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) which accepts an iterable of attribute names.

e.g.

```
attrs = ['max', 'min', 'mean']
result = [r() for r in attrgetter(*attrs)(df['close'])]
```

But in this case since you need to call the `getattr` result again, it's not a Pythonic way to use `operator.attrgetter()`. Instead you could dimply loop over the attrs and just call the result manually in a list comprehension.

```
[getattr(df['close'], attr)() for attr in attrs]
```

Comment: When trying either of those options, my result comes out to be: "soxs <bound method Series.mean of 0         NaN, Name: close, Length: 506, dtype: float64>" Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @EMZ It seems that it's returning a bound method. You should call the result(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use `methdcaller` instead of `attrgetter` for calling methods.

`max`, `min` and `mean` are all methods of `pandas.Series`, not attributes. Since `methodcaller` only calls one method at a time, you can apply multiple methods via a comprehension.

Here's a complete example:

```
from operator import methodcaller
import pandas as pd

def get_stat(df, stat):
    return {i: methodcaller(i)(df['close']) for i in stat}

df_input = pd.DataFrame({'close': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

res = get_stat(df_input, ['max', 'min', 'mean'])

print(res)

{'max': 5, 'min': 1, 'mean': 3.0}
```